# What does "specific" exactly mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> The agreement is **specific** to those provisions specified in the manual.

In the example above, does "is specific to" mean "match"? I am not sure if this sentence means "The agreement matches/fits those provisions". The meanings of "specific" defined in dictionaries seem vague for this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the agreement is only valid within the context of those provisions specified in the manual.

Something that is *specific to a particular thing* is connected with that thing *only*.

> Send your resume with a cover letter that is *specific to* that particular job.
>
> The disease seems to be *specific to* (= only found in) certain types of plant.
>
> a disease *specific to* horses